# what is the difference between call back and higher order functions?

Tags: javascript, callback, difference, higher-order-functions

call back functions are those Functions that are used as an argument to another function then what is higher order function ?

Comment: "*Higher-order functions are functions which either take functions as arguments or return them as output (or both).*" from the tag description of [[tag:higher-order-functions]]

Comment: 1. Callback function is a function that is passed to another function. 2. Higher-order function is a function that returns another function and/or takes another function (callback) an an argument.

Answer (score 0):

A function which accepts another function as an argument or returns any function is called *higher order function*, whereas the function which is passed as a parameter in another function (or you may call higher order function) is known as *call back function*.